# Using dynamic variables with reReplaceNoCase in a cfloop

Tags: struct, coldfusion, cfloop

I'm using a cfloop to insert dynamic form values into a session struct. I use reReplaceNoCase to sanitize the input and am running into an issue trying to use dynamic form field names in the reReplaceNoCase method. I've tried different naming schemes but can't nail down the syntax. In the posted code, FORM.RTchoice[r] is what is failing and shows the error: Element RTCHOICE is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String;.. How do I get the form fields to increment by "r" correctly?

```
<cfloop index="r" from="1" to="#APPLICATION.theCount#">
   <cfset a = StructInsert(SESSION.USER_OBJECT, "RTchoice#r#", "#reReplaceNoCase(FORM.RTchoice[r], "[^a-zA-Z0-9.,(\s)-]", "", "all")#", 1)>
    </cfloop>
```

Comment: That’s because form.rtChoice is a string. All form variables are simple values. Why do you think it should be a struct?

Comment: I assumed from "dynamic form field names" that the OP meant that there are form fields named `RTchoice1` , `RTchoice2` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

`<cfset a = StructInsert(SESSION.USER_OBJECT, "RTchoice#r#", reReplaceNoCase(FORM['RTchoice#r#'], "[^a-zA-Z0-9.,(\s)-]", "", "all"), 1)>`

Or

`<cfset a = StructInsert(SESSION.USER_OBJECT, "RTchoice#r#", reReplaceNoCase(FORM['RTchoice'&r], "[^a-zA-Z0-9.,(\s)-]", "", "all"), 1)>`

Eg: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=cafebd5c-f4b5-4fc7-93bf-ff81ca97c234/00f6a79c-7f5f-42b2-b567-8a8a371fa8aa/3c7d3229-f65f-4afe-8538-306d98adf25f.cfm

Comment: Not directly related to the issue, but.. unless there is a specific reason for using StructInsert(), it is simpler to use structure notation imo, ie `<cfset someStruct["dynamicKeyName"] = ....>`

Comment: You make a good point @SOS. I've changed my syntax accordingly.

Comment: Good point. I would only be using `StructInsert()` in this sort of situation if it was because I _wanted_ an exception to be thrown in conjunction with `allowOverwrite=false`

Comment: Would be good to add an example, so future readers don't think you *have* to use StructInsert for dynamic variables :-)